# How to replicate my results from running n LASSOs iteratively using elastic net but now with glmnet

Tags: r, machine-learning, replication, feature-selection, lasso-regression

I have successfully run LASSO Regressions on each of n data sets within the 'datasets' list in my R Environment/Workspace using the enet function from the elastic net library in R, but just to ensure there is nothing arbitrary about my results based on how I wrote my code, I want to repeat all of this using the glmnet function from the library of the same name.

My existing code is shown below:

```
set.seed(100)     # to ensure replicability
L_fits <- lapply(data, function(i) 
               enet(x = as.matrix(select(i, starts_with("X"))), 
                    y = i$Y, lambda = 0, normalize = FALSE))

# This stores and prints out all of the regression 
# equation specifications selected by LASSO when called
L_Coeffs <- lapply(L_fits, 
                       function(j) predict(j, x = as.matrix(select(j, starts_with("X"))), 
                                           s = 0.1, mode = "fraction", 
                                           type = "coefficients")[["coefficients"]])

### Write my own custom function which will separate out and return a 
### new list containing just the Independent Variables/Factors/Predictors
### which are 'selected' or chosen for each individual dataset. 
LASSOs_Selections <- lapply(L_Coeffs, function(k) names(k[k > 0]))
```

I have already figured it out this far, but I can't figure out how to capture just the coefficients, then just the variables selected by LASSO:

```
set.seed(100)     # to ensure replicability
L_fits <- lapply(data, function(i) 
               glmnet(x = as.matrix(select(i, starts_with("X"))), 
                      y = i$Y, alpha = 0))

7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one approach:

```
library(glmnet)
library(dplyr) ## for convenience filtering

## load glmnet sample data:
data(QuickStartExample)

## create two sample datasets
## lists with components x (20 x 10 matrix) and y:
ex1 = ex2 = QuickStartExample
ex2$x = ex2$x * (1 + .05 * rnorm(200))
```

- [fit `glmnet` models](https://glmnet.stanford.edu/articles/glmnet.html) for example datasets:

```
L_fits = list(ex1, ex2) |>
  Map(f = \(ex) glmnet(x = ex$x, y = ex$y, alpha = 1))
```

*`|>` is R's native pipe operator, and `\(x) x` is shorthand for `function(x) x`*

- extract coefficients:

```
L_coefs = L_fits |> 
  Map(f = \(model) coef(model, s = .1))
```

*note the specification of lambda: s = .1:
otherwise, a matrix of coefficients for lambda = 1 : 10 * .1 will be returned*

- convert coefficients from sparse matrix via dense matrix to dataframe
  and retain "kept" variables (with coefficient != 0)

```
L_coefs |>
  Map(f = \(matr) matr |> as.matrix() |> 
                  as.data.frame() |>
                  filter(s1 != 0)
      )
```

**edit**

to return only the variables retained by `glmnet::glmnet`, you can e.g. keep only the filtered dataframes' rownames (which correspond to the variable names):

```
L_coefs |>
  Map(f = \(matr) matr |> as.matrix() |> 
                  as.data.frame() |>
                  filter(s1 != 0) |> 
                  rownames()
      )
```

Comment: wow, I would never have thought to use anything resembling this approach, looks promising! I'll try it when I get back to my place later today and let you know how it goes. Appreciate it!

Comment: this answer definitely gets me the coefficients for each variable/column, but the way it is returning them is as a numeric: str(L_coefs[[1]]@x)
 num [1:31] 1.0082 0.0247 -0.0568 -0.024 0.032 ...
and I need to extract the names of all the positive coefficients, what their coefficients actually are is not the goal in my application, just which candidate variables are 'selected' by LASSO.

Comment: Please mind to mark the answer as accepted (if that's the case of course).

Comment: @I_O I got really sick over the past few days, sorry for the delay, now I am not exactly sure what to do because you latest edit seems to work, but I am getting the wrong results. I feel like this means I may have written the code for my original function to estimate all n LASSOs wrong. It returns all 30 candidate regressors and the intercept as well for each and every dataset now... 
Should I ask a new question or edit my question with this or what? Not sure how to proceed.

Comment: @I_O I have accepted your answer out of politeness and not wanting to complicate anything, but I have now asked a follow up question explaining the surprising issue that has emerged now which you may be interested in answering as well:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75167391/correcting-the-output-strictly-in-terms-the-features-variables-selected-of-n-l